# How to set absolutely value for clip-path: polygon in css?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to create a responsive message balloon with TailwindCSS.

I'm using clip-path: polygon to make the shape. But the shape's values using relatively value then my shape become incorrect when I change the width.

I created two shapes because I need the gradient border.

My expected: [image]

Error when responsive: [image]

I expect it to keep the shape in the below picture (I don't know how to call it) is absolutely, it will not change when responsive but the width of the shape can change.

Here is my code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/P5nKIREryg

Comment: How accurate do you want it to be - at the moment even before the actual break in the brown the angle of the white and the angle of the brown are very different. You'd need to recalculate angles and heights on each resize to get it exact. If being exact isn't important then a few media queries will probably suffice.

Comment: @AHaworth I must use javascript to do that, right?

Comment: Probably, to get exact accuracy, but a couple of media queries might be good enough for what  you want.